# Its fine to create a list that holds multiple variable types?

Tags: list

Generally speaking, its fine to create a list that holds multiple variable types?
For example

```
list = [0,"hello",True,0.25,[0,5]]
```

Im not asking IF i can do this (because for example you can in python), Im just asking if it is considered a bad (or messy) thing to do or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you could create a list of `Object` to store all of that. How would you know what was in each position? We are using a `Hashtable` to store multiple data types, but we are also storing keys, so we know what to expect when we retrieve it.

Here's an example in a C# console application:

```cs
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     object[] list = { 0, "hello", true, 0.25, (new object[]{ 0, 5 }) };

     foreach (var item in list)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().ToString() + ": " + item.ToString());
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Comment: It's only bad/messy if there's a better way to store the data. For instance, if you are always going to have that specific set of values (integer, string, boolean, double, int array), you may want to create a Class, or at least a Struct, to store the values into properties. Then, you can store multiple instances of those in a `List<T>` or the like.

Comment: Also, you didn't specify a language, so I gave an example in my primary one. I'm sure the rules are similar in other languages. It's just a matter of what options you have. I've basically done the same in VB6.